# Expression Tree that can represent an object OR a list of that object?

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

```
public returnType ReturnProperty<T>(Expression<Func<T, returnType>> property) where T : MyObject
{
  // Some code or something
}
```

Obviously this is not my actual function, but basically what I want is to be able to select either an object of `MyObject` or an object of `List<MyObject>`. What should I replace `returnType` with for this to be possible? Is it possible at all? Do I have alternatives besides making `returnType` be `object`?

Note: Also, I did not know what tags to put on this question, sorry.

Edit: Also, the reason I need to be able to do both is I wanted to have an array of them or something. Like `Expression<Func<T, returnType>>[] properties`. Maybe this gives me more or less options.

Comment: er, on a hunch, no, not possible to return a type that represents both an instance of an object or its generic enumerable equivalent. for what it's worth, consider returning IEnumerable<T> and if only a single element is returned it is a collection of 1.

Comment: +1 for johnny g's suggestion; it's very easy to turn a single item into an IEnumerable of that item by using "new MyObject[] { item }"

Comment: This works for the return type, but what about inside the Expression?

Answer (score 0):

You can have the function return object.  object is anything, so it could be MyObject or List<MyObject>.  You can then do things like this:

```
object retval = ReturnProperty(...)
if (retval is MyObject)
{
}
else if (retval is IEnumerable<MyObject>)    // Works for List, array, etc.
{
}
```

Comment: "Do I have alternatives besides making `returnType` be `object`?" I have all of my database objects inherit from one class, and I would like this function to only take in objects (and list of objects) from this class.

Comment: No, because MyObject and List<MyObject> have nothing in common.  One does not inherit from the other and they share no interface, so the "least common denominator" if you will, is object.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that if you can't write it as direct c# code, you can't write it as an expression tree.

Not that I think it's at all a good idea, but you *could* define a collection which has an implicit conversion from the contained type, which would allow you to use an expression which only takes a collection as a parameter, e.g.:

```
private static void ProcessItems(ItemCollection c) {}
ProcessItems(new Item());

// ...

class Item {}

class ItemCollection : List<Item>
{
    public static implicit operator ItemCollection(Item item)
    {
        return new ItemCollection {item};
    }
}
```